# How to create a Python virtualenv within my project directory with a specific (but uninstalled) python version

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm a fan of virtual environments, and I also like to keep my `virtualenv`s in the root project directory. This helps me keep track of where they are and allows me to call them generic names, like `.venv`.

But I need a way to install specific versions of python for use with my `virtualenv`s. All roads seem to point to `pyenv`.

Unless I'm misunderstanding how `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` work, this libary seems to insist on burying my actual virtualenv somewhere in the `~/.pyenv` folder, and leaving me with a `.python-version` file, which I'd rather not have.

Isn't there a way to install specific versions of python with the ease of use of `pyenv`, but then create my virtual environments in the traditional way, inside my project directory, thus removing my projects's dependency on `pyenv` after the virtual environment has been created?

Answer (score 14):

```sh
# you need install the target version first
pyenv install 3.9.5
# then sets a shell-specific Python version
pyenv shell 3.9.5
# use this python version to create virtualenv
python -m venv .venv
# or use virtualenv
virtualenv .venv -p $(pyenv which python)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you kind sir!

Comment: I wish the docs made this as clear! One thing to note for anyone else using this, if you are changing the global python and you have any projects in the system that precede pyenv's installation, be sure to set the global back to whichever python you were using before running those projects.

Comment: Perfect! I would like to suggest using `pyenv local 3.9.5` or even `cd <my-project> && pyenv local 3.9.5` and don't mess up your global Python installation as suggested  @user3507825.