# pyvenv not showing the correct python version

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I have `python 3.11.2` installed on my local machine. For a specific project I need to use `python 3.9.13`

So I installed pyenv, created a new directory and isntalled python version 3.9.13 in that directory. In the same directory I created a new virtual environment by doing: `.\.venv\Scripts\activate`. After that in Visual Code I selected the correct python version which is 3.9.13. Everything looks good as you would say. However, when I do python -V in my command line in VS code (inside the virtual environment) I receive the following output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDofq.png)

Comment: How did you create the `virtualenv` (not activating)? Dose this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69073999/15174775) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual env and add specific python version in on run. For example:

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.9.13
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following error: RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.9.13'

Comment: Did you install `python3.9.13`?

Comment: I installed it using pyenv yes. I could not install it from the python website because it did not contain any exe file.

Comment: Here are download links: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3913/.